# How to detect TMux level

Tags: tmux

Is there any way to detect how many levels of tmux I'm currently in? I've been able to hack it with 2 levels by simply checking `[[ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" && -n "$TMUX" ]]`, so I can have one level on the client and one on the server. I use that check to setup a different prefix (ctrl-a, ctrl-b).

But now I'm finding I want to ssh from inside the server shell, so would like even a third level, thus requiring a third prefix combination to be setup.

[image: Obligatory Inception meme]

Comment: In researching this I found no methods that would allow you to do this. So you're likely going to have to hack something together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there is no way to check what tmux depth you are currently on. However you can easily bake your own solution. Just make a variable in your `.bashrc`/`.bash_profile`/`.profile` like so:

```
if [[ ! -n "${LC_NESTING_DEPTH}" ]]; then
    export LC_NESTING_DEPTH=1
else
    export LC_NESTING_DEPTH=$(expr 1 + $LC_NESTING_DEPTH)
fi
```

Since the .bashrc gets loaded every time you enter tmux, the variable gets incremented two. You can even pass the variable over ssh by adding `SendEnv LC_NESTING_DEPTH` to the `~/.ssh/config` on your machine, and `AcceptEnv LC_NESTING_DEPTH` in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the machine you're ssh-ing to (See `man ssh_config` and `man sshd_config` for more info on that). I couldn't test ssh-ing from a running ssh session, but I assume you can pass the variable on from there as well.